# What openings fit the tastes of a positional player?

Tags: opening, positional-play, style

I am a very positional player, but, I cannot find good openings that suit my tastes. What are the lists of openings that result in strategic / positional positions?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Please limit it to something more useful and less vague.

Comment: Copy and paste your question to ChatGPT and you will get a great list.

Comment: If you cannot answer this question, how do you know you are a positional player? What does that term mean to you? I hope something more that just not being very good at tactics.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with ruy lopez with white and sicillian defence caro-kann for black, these openings have a positional taste in them, in the opening phase your main objective is to prepare your pieces for the middle game and you have to think about the positional impact of each move of both you and your opponent.